# Reactjs: ¿Cuál puede ser el motivo por el que el array que contiene un objeto inicial se setea a un array vacío al cargar el componente?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

Estoy trabajando con Reactjs, Typescipt y componentes de MUI. He creado un filtro compuesto por un Autocomplete y un Slider. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este filtro tiene debajo un botón "Add" cuya función es duplicarlo para añadir más opciones para filtrar. Para mostar este componente recorro un array que tiene un objeto inicial de manera que siempre haya un filtro renderizado al cargar la página. Sin embargo, por algún motivo que estoy pasando por alto, una vez terminada de cargar la página me setea el array a un array vacío con lo que el componente desaparece.

El filtro en sí funciona correctamente, pero en algún momento estoy seteando el array con el objeto inicial a un array vacío, pero no doy con el motivo de esto.

Esta es la parte del código del componente del filtro con las funcionalidades:

```js
export const initNarrative = {
    id: "",
    label: "",
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
} as TLSPMNarrativeBase;

export const LSPMFilter = ({ lspmNarratives, setLspmNarratives }: ILSPMFilterParams): JSX.Element => {
    const intl = useIntl();
    const classes = LSPMFilterStyles();

    const [lspmFilters, setLspmFilters] = useState<TLSPMNarrativeBase[]>([initNarrative]);
    const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
    
    const [isValid, setIsValid] = useState<boolean>(true);

    const handleOnChange = (index: number, value: TLSPMNarrativeBase | null, reason: AutocompleteChangeReason) => {
        const updatedFilters = [...lspmFilters];

        updatedFilters[index].id = value?.id ? value.id : null;
        updatedFilters[index].label = LSPMFilterOptions.find((option) => option.id === value?.id)?.label || "";

        setLspmFilters(updatedFilters);
        setLspmNarratives(updatedFilters);
    };

    const handleOnChangeRanges = (index: number, newValue: RangeType) => {
        const newRanges = [...lspmFilters];
        if (newValue) {
            if (newValue.minimum >= 0 || newValue.maximum <= 100) {
                newRanges[index].min = newValue.minimum;
                newRanges[index].max = newValue.maximum;
                setIsValid(true);
            } else {
                setIsValid(false);
                return;
            }
        }

        setLspmFilters(newRanges);
        setLspmNarratives(newRanges);
    };

    const getOptionLabel = (option: TLSPMNarrativeBase) => `${option.label}`;

    const getOptionSelected = (option: TLSPMNarrativeBase, value: TLSPMNarrativeBase) => {
        return option.label === value.label;
    };

    const handleInputChange = (event: React.SyntheticEvent, value: string, reason: string) => {
        if (reason !== "reset" && value !== "") {
            setInputValue(value);
            return;
        }

        if (reason === "clear") {
            setInputValue("");
        }
    };

    const handleRemoveFilter = (index: number) => {
        const updatedFilters = lspmFilters.filter((_, i) => i !== index);
        setLspmFilters(updatedFilters);
        setLspmNarratives(updatedFilters);
    };

    const onClickAddFilter = () => {
        const newFilters = [...lspmFilters, { id: "", label: "", min: 0, max: 100 }];
        
        setLspmFilters(newFilters);
        setLspmNarratives(newFilters);
    };

    const optionRender = (props: React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLLIElement>, option: TLSPMNarrativeBase) => {
        return (
            <li {...props}>
                <Box>
                    <span>{option.label}</span>
                </Box>
            </li>
        );
    };

    return (
        <Box className={classes.filterContainer}>
            <Box className={classes.lspmSearchBoxHeader}>
                <CustomIcon className={classes.labelIcon} icon={icons.equalizer} />
                <Typography className={classes.labelTitle}>
                    {intl.formatMessage({ id: "talent.filters.lspm" })}
                </Typography>
            </Box>
            {/* Search Box */}
            <Box>
                {lspmNarratives.map((filter, index) => (
                    <Box key={index} className={classes.filterWrapper}>
                        <Autocomplete
                            id={`selected-narraive-${index}`}
                            className={classes.lspmSearchBox}
                            getOptionDisabled={(option) =>
                                lspmNarratives.some((filter, i) => i !== index && filter.id === option.id)
                            }
                            value={
                                filter.label
                                    ? LSPMFilterOptions.find((option) => option.id === filter.id) || null
                                    : null
                            }
                            options={LSPMFilterOptions}
                            isOptionEqualToValue={getOptionSelected}
                            getOptionLabel={getOptionLabel}
                            renderOption={optionRender}
                            renderInput={(params) => (
                                <TextField
                                    {...params}
                                    size="small"
                                    placeholder={intl.formatMessage({ id: "talent.filters.lspm.searchPlaceholder" })}
                                />
                            )}
                            onInputChange={handleInputChange}
                            onChange={(ev, newValue, reason) => handleOnChange(index, newValue, reason)}
                        />
                        {/* Range Slider */}
                        <Box
                            className={classes.sliderWrapper}
                            sx={{
                                ...(!filter.id && { pointerEvents: "none" }),
                            }}
                        >
                            <TalentSlider
                                id="lspm-range-selector"
                                value={[filter.min, filter.max]}
                                minLinear={0}
                                maxLinear={100}
                                onChange={(value) => handleOnChangeRanges(index, value)}
                                numberFormatProps={{
                                    isNumericString: true,
                                }}
                                isDisabled={filter.id === "" || filter.id === null ? true : false}
                            />
                        </Box>

                        <Box>
                            {index > 0 ? (
                                <IconButton
                                    aria-label="delete"
                                    className={classes.deleteButton}
                                    onClick={() => handleRemoveFilter(index)}
                                >
                                    <ClearIcon fontSize="small" />
                                </IconButton>
                            ) : null}
                        </Box>
                    </Box>
                ))}
            </Box>
            <LinkButton
                Icon={<AddCircleRoundedIcon sx={{ fontSize: 16 }} />}
                label={<FormattedMessage id="talent.filters,lspm.addNarrative" />}
                onClick={onClickAddFilter}
            />
        </Box>
    );
};

export default LSPMFilter;
```

Y acá la sección del componente padre que renderiza el componente del filtro:

```js
    const [narrativesArr, setNarrativesArr] = useState<TLSPMNarrativeBase[]>([initNarrative]);

<Box className={classes.filterWrapper}>
    <LSPMFilter lspmNarratives={narrativesArr} setLspmNarratives={setNarrativesArr} />
</Box>
```

Alguna ayuda para encontrar el motivo por el cuál no se renderiza el primer componente? No logro ver que estoy pasando por alto o que estoy haciendo mal.

Comment: Si el estado que se vuelve array vacio es `narrativesArr` entonces el set involucrado es `setNarrativesArr`, pero ambos vienen desde un componente padre, ahora este set pasa como `props` con el nombre de `setLspmNarratives` sugiero que verifiques con consola el valor que envias a este set en cada `handle`, pues en alguno de ellos sobreescribes con un array vacío. Si pudieras compartir un sandbox...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema estaba en el componente padre, en otra parte del código. A la hora de cargar los filtros guardados si no había data de retorno me estaba pasando un array vacío. Lo he solucionado modificando la condición para que en ese caso me retorne el array con el objeto por defecto, es decir algo así: `setNarrativeArray((narrative) => results.state.data?.filters?......lspmNarratives ? narrative);`